# Understanding the behavior of Keras EarlyStopping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm using `tensorflow 2.4.0`, and here's the code of the `tf.keras` EarlyStopping callback, in particular the method, of the `EarlyStopping` class, called at the end of each epoch (`on_epoch_end`):

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
  current = self.get_monitor_value(logs).
  if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
    self.best = current
    self.wait = 0
    if self.restore_best_weights:
      self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
  else:
    self.wait += 1
    if self.wait >= self.patience:
      self.stopped_epoch = epoch
      self.model.stop_training = True
      if self.restore_best_weights:
        if self.verbose > 0:
          print('Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.')
        self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
```

where, since, in my case, the monitored quantity is the `val_loss`:

```
self.monitor_op = np.less
```

In essence, the code performs this logic:

```
If (current - min_delta) < best:
      best = current;
      wait = 0
Otherwise:
      wait += 1;
      if wait >= patience:
            stop training
```

Then if, for example:

- `min_delta = 0.1`
- `current = 0.9`
- `best = 0.85`

we have that `(current - min_delta) < best`, thus:

- `best = current (=0.9)`
- `wait = 0`

So, `best` is now associated to a worse value than the previous one (`0.9` instead of `0.85`); is it the correct/expected behavior of EarlyStopping?
It's seems strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the `init` [method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/callbacks.py#L1800) of the `EarlyStopping` class, you should see something like this:

```py
if self.monitor_op == np.greater:
 self.min_delta *= 1
else:
 self.min_delta *= -1
```

So, since we know `self.monitor_op = np.less`, I think `min_delta` is actually -0.1 in your case and the if statement evaluation is something like: `(0.9-(-0.1)) < 0.85`. I am assuming you have an `EarlyStopping` callback defined as:

```py
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
```

Note also what `min_delta` actually [is](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping):

> Minimum change in the monitored quantity to qualify as an improvement,
> i.e. an absolute change of less than min_delta, will count as no
> improvement.